# 301 redirect to remove subdirectory and file extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have recently migrated a site that has all blog posts in a `/blog/` subdirectory so URLs were formed like this:

`www.example.com/blog/post-name.shtml`

There are also pages in the root directory like this:

`www.example.com/page-name.htm`

It is now migrated to WordPress with the URL structure being:

`www.example.com/post-name` and `www.example.com/page-name` respectively. We would like to keep the new URL structure that way.

How do I:

1. Remove the `blog` subdirectory
2. Remove .html, .shtml, and .htm from URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule as **very first rule** in `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(?:blog/)?([^.]+)\.s?html?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Will this cover files with the .htm and .shtml extensions as well (they're all over the place on the old site)? What about the pages in the root directory of the old domain as well?

Comment: ok check updated rule. It has to be first rule in root .htaccess and yes it takes care of `html`, `.htm`, `.shtml`